# Notation of de Rham Complex of a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I am confused by some notation used in Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds* (2nd edition) to describe the de Rham complex on a manifold. Below I quote the relevant portion from Chapter 25 (page no. 281).

> The vector space $\Omega^*(M)$ of differential forms on a manifold $M$ together with the exterior derivative $d$ is a cochain complex, the de Rham complex of $M$:

$$\color{red}{0} \to \Omega^0(M) \xrightarrow{d} \Omega^1(M) \xrightarrow{d} \Omega^2(M) \xrightarrow{d} \cdots, d \circ d =0.$$

What does the $0$ (I have colored it red) stand for here? Its meaning is not clear to me.

Comment: The initial object of the category of vector spaces : the vector space$\{0\}$. The first arrow is the constant map $x \mapsto 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This $0$ is the initial object of the category of vector spaces : the vector space with only one element (its $0$). The first arrow is the constant map $x \mapsto 0$.

Comment: Why do we need this part $0 \to \Omega^0(M)$ in the sequence?

Comment: @rainman Anyway that is the only morphism $0 \mapsto \Omega(M)$, but explicit is better than implicit. Oh, and exact sequences starting and stoping with $0$ are easier to deal with.

Comment: This is a complex, not an exact sequence! $d$ is never injective on $\Omega^0(M)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you I got confused. Why do we want the complex to start with $0$ please?

Is it just because it preserves the $d \circ d = 0$ property for the index 0?

Comment: I personally never start with the $0$, but it isn’t wrong. I suppose it helps formally to define $H^0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Would you mind to elaborate on it, please?